# How to match negative and positive numbers within a group?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe like the one below

```
ItemNo    OrderAmount     Date
3845         320       2020-01-21
3245        -100       2020-01-20
4045        -200       2020-01-20
3845         300       2020-01-19
3845         320       2020-01-18
3245         100       2020-01-18
3645         230       2020-01-18
3645        -230       2020-01-18
3245        -100       2020-01-18
3845         320       2020-01-17
4045           0       2020-01-17
3845         320       2020-01-17
3845        -300       2020-01-17
3245         200       2020-01-17
3645         230       2020-01-16
4045         200       2020-01-15
3845        -300       2020-01-15
3245         100       2020-01-15
3245         100       2020-01-15
3845         320       2020-01-15
4045         240       2020-01-15
4045           0       2020-01-15
```

I wish to match negative and positive numbers within a group (ItemNo), and then delete the matched rows from the data frame. If the OrderAmount is 0, then it is kept in the dataframe. I want the output to be

```
ItemNo    OrderAmount     Date
3845          320       2020-01-21
3845          320       2020-01-18
3245          100       2020-01-18
3645          230       2020-01-18
3845          320       2020-01-17
4045            0       2020-01-17
3845          320       2020-01-17
3845         -300       2020-01-17
3245          200       2020-01-17
3845          320       2020-01-15
4045          240       2020-01-15
4045            0       2020-01-15
```

I have tried using:

```
# Dataframe
DF <- data.frame(ItemNo=c(3845,3245,4045,3845,3845,3245,3645,3645,3245,3845,4045,3845,3845,3245,3645,4045,3845,3245,3245,3845,4045,4045),
                 OrderAmount = c(320,-100,-200,300,320,100,230,-230,-100,320,0,320,-300,200,230,200,-300,100,100,320,240,0),
                 Date = c("2020-01-21","2020-01-20","2020-01-20","2020-01-19","2020-01-18","2020-01-18","2020-01-18","2020-01-18","2020-01-18","2020-01-17","2020-01-17","2020-01-17","2020-01-17","2020-01-17","2020-01-16","2020-01-15","2020-01-15","2020-01-15","2020-01-15","2020-01-15","2020-01-15","2020-01-15"))
DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date)
# Order by date -> oldest first
DF <- DF[order(desc(DF$Date)),]

DF %>%
  group_by(ItemNo, nvalue = abs(OrderAmount)) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(OrderAmount)) %>%
  filter(sum(OrderAmount) >= 0) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-nvalue)
```

E.g. I want the output for ItemNo 3245 to be

```
ItemNo    OrderAmount     Date
3245        -100       2020-01-20 #DELETE: Matched with 5. Row
3245         100       2020-01-18
3245        -100       2020-01-18 #DELETE: Matched with 6. Row
3245         200       2020-01-17 
3245         100       2020-01-15 #DELETE: Matched with 1. Row
3245         100       2020-01-15 #DELETE: Matched with 3. Row
```

Comment: PLease describe exactly what the matching pattern should be. E.g. it is not clear to me why the 4. row in your input data frame is deleted. In addition, please provide a: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The 4. row is matched with 17. row, since it is in the same group, and is the same OrderAmount with opposite sign. There needs to be a one-to-one match on OrderAmount with opposite sign within the same group.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky algorithm to solve without iteratively building or weeding out a data frame, which would be slow. Here's one possible solution, but it is fairly complex:

```r
balanced_table <- function(d) {
  d <- d[order(d$Date),]
  x <- d$OrderAmount
  x <- factor(x, c(unique(abs(x[x != 0])), 0, -unique(abs(x[x != 0]))))
  x <- table(x)
  neg <- -x[as.numeric(names(x)) < 0]
  pos <- x[as.numeric(names(x)) > 0]
  names(neg) <- -as.numeric(names(neg))
  totals <- pos + neg
  final <- c(totals, x[as.numeric(names(x)) == 0])
  names(final)[final < 0] <- -as.numeric(names(final)[final < 0])
  final[final < 0] <- -final[final < 0]
  final
  res <- tidyr::uncount(as.data.frame(as.table(final[final != 0])), Freq)
  vals <- as.numeric(as.character(res$Var1))
  do.call(rbind, lapply(split(vals, vals), function(v) {
    d[which(d$OrderAmount == v[1])[seq_along(v)],]
  }))
}

`rownames<-`(do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$ItemNo), balanced_table)), NULL)
#>    ItemNo OrderAmount       Date
#> 1    3245         100 2020-01-15
#> 2    3245         200 2020-01-17
#> 3    3645         230 2020-01-16
#> 4    3845        -300 2020-01-15
#> 5    3845         320 2020-01-15
#> 6    3845         320 2020-01-17
#> 7    3845         320 2020-01-17
#> 8    3845         320 2020-01-18
#> 9    3845         320 2020-01-21
#> 10   4045           0 2020-01-15
#> 11   4045           0 2020-01-17
#> 12   4045         240 2020-01-15
```

Or, to keep the original ordering and thus match the expected output of your question:

```r
df$row <- seq(nrow(df))
df2 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$ItemNo), balanced_table))
`rownames<-`(df2[order(df2$row), names(df2) != "row"], NULL)
#>    ItemNo OrderAmount       Date
#> 1    3845         320 2020-01-21
#> 2    3845         320 2020-01-18
#> 3    3845         320 2020-01-17
#> 4    4045           0 2020-01-17
#> 5    3845         320 2020-01-17
#> 6    3245         200 2020-01-17
#> 7    3645         230 2020-01-16
#> 8    3845        -300 2020-01-15
#> 9    3245         100 2020-01-15
#> 10   3845         320 2020-01-15
#> 11   4045         240 2020-01-15
#> 12   4045           0 2020-01-15
```

---

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(ItemNo = c(3845L, 3245L, 4045L, 3845L, 3845L, 
3245L, 3645L, 3645L, 3245L, 3845L, 4045L, 3845L, 3845L, 3245L, 
3645L, 4045L, 3845L, 3245L, 3245L, 3845L, 4045L, 4045L), OrderAmount = c(320L, 
-100L, -200L, 300L, 320L, 100L, 230L, -230L, -100L, 320L, 0L, 
320L, -300L, 200L, 230L, 200L, -300L, 100L, 100L, 320L, 240L, 
0L), Date = structure(c(18282, 18281, 18281, 18280, 18279, 18279, 
18279, 18279, 18279, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18278, 18277, 
18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276, 18276), class = "Date")), 
row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = "data.frame")

df
#>    ItemNo OrderAmount       Date
#> 1    3845         320 2020-01-21
#> 2    3245        -100 2020-01-20
#> 3    4045        -200 2020-01-20
#> 4    3845         300 2020-01-19
#> 5    3845         320 2020-01-18
#> 6    3245         100 2020-01-18
#> 7    3645         230 2020-01-18
#> 8    3645        -230 2020-01-18
#> 9    3245        -100 2020-01-18
#> 10   3845         320 2020-01-17
#> 11   4045           0 2020-01-17
#> 12   3845         320 2020-01-17
#> 13   3845        -300 2020-01-17
#> 14   3245         200 2020-01-17
#> 15   3645         230 2020-01-16
#> 16   4045         200 2020-01-15
#> 17   3845        -300 2020-01-15
#> 18   3245         100 2020-01-15
#> 19   3245         100 2020-01-15
#> 20   3845         320 2020-01-15
#> 21   4045         240 2020-01-15
#> 22   4045           0 2020-01-15
```

Comment: Thanks, this also seemed to work. I found a less complex way, and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it seemed to work:

```
DF <- data.frame(ItemNo=c(3845,3245,4045,3845,3845,3245,3645,3645,3245,3845,4045,3845,3845,3245,3645,4045,3845,3245,3245,3845,4045,4045),
                 OrderAmount = c(320,-100,-200,300,320,100,230,-230,-100,320,0,320,-300,200,230,200,-300,100,100,320,240,0),
                 Date = c("2020-01-21","2020-01-20","2020-01-20","2020-01-19","2020-01-18","2020-01-18","2020-01-18","2020-01-18","2020-01-18","2020-01-17","2020-01-17","2020-01-17","2020-01-17","2020-01-17","2020-01-16","2020-01-15","2020-01-15","2020-01-15","2020-01-15","2020-01-15","2020-01-15","2020-01-15"))

DF$Date <- as.character(DF$Date)
DF <- DF[order(DF$Date),]
DF$rowNumber <- 1:nrow(DF)
DF_TEMP <- DF %>%
    group_by(ItemNo, OrderAmount) %>% 
    mutate(id_row = row_number()) %>%
    group_by(ItemNo, id_row, ab = abs(OrderAmount)) %>%
    filter(n() > 1) %>% ungroup() %>%
    select(-id_row, -ab)
DF <- DF[!(DF$rowNumber %in% DF_TEMP$rowNumber),]
```